# Is there a private calendar plugin for WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, calendar, private

I am looking for a calendar that can be completely private.  So far I have only found calendars that can have private events. I need a calendar to be in a members' only section so the whole calendar has to be able to be private.

I realize this may not exist as I have been searching the internet for an hour on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

In any calendar plugin it should really easy allow access only to logged in users: These looks pretty nice:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/all-in-one-event-calendar/screenshots/
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/calendar/screenshots/

Then you must to put following code in a suitable hook to force login, ie, totally private access. 8)

```
if ( ! is_user_logged_in())
{
    wp_redirect(wp_login_url());
    exit;
}
```